# Does where() method have the same power like whereRaw() method?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a **Video** model and a **Tag** model. Let's say I would like to get all videos that have tags, maybe all the videos that have more than three relations with tags. I would do this:

```
Video::has('tags', '>=', 3)->get();
```

If I want do add more constrains, for example get all videos with at least 3 tags and the tag name should contain *'something'*. I could do something like this:

```
Video::whereHas('tags' function(Builder $query){$query->where('name', 'like', '%something%');}, '>=', 3)->get();
```

But what if I would like to do something more, like only tags with odd/even id to be counted. Something like `fmod('id', 2)` to be used inside the closure. To check if the id is even or odd. **Since I can't do something like:** `$query->where('id%2', '=', 0 );`. Well, in this case I know I could use `$query->where('name', 'like', '%something%')->whereRaw('tags.id%2=0');`. But is there any other way using where() method?

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. There's obviously not a `whereEvenNumber` method, so what you've got there is your best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where()` first parameter will always be the column, but in cases where you specifies columns in the queries like `where()` and `select()`, you can use `DB::raw()`; This should make this syntax viable, which i think is the best solution the `Eloquent` ORM.

```
->where(DB::raw('tags.id%2'), 0);
```

Comment: This is what I meant. Basically is the same idea as `whereRaw()` but I wanted to use `where()` to be able to do the same thing. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you liked it